# javascript, colorbox - dynamically get ID

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to grab an id dynamically using to load up content in a modal window, but I am having difficulty grabbing the id.

Here is the example I posted up on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4GGS/)

The divs with class `ticket_details` and anchor tag with class `dialog_link` is generated dynamically using PHP.

If you need more clarification, let me know! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Uh, why not use an actual ID `<div id='ID21' class='something'></div>`. Also, class/id names can't start with a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following selector `var e = $('.ticket_details');` returns a **list** of divs. What you need to do is iterate through all of the returned divs and do whatever you want, something like this: `$('.ticket_details').each(function () { console.log($(this).attr('class')); });`

Answer (score 0):

Both the comment by **tjameson** and the answer by **Ali** are spot-on.

Although it's not technically incorrect to assign classes that are unique, it's also not a best practice. (I'm thinking about future maintainers here.)  The ID element is more to your purposes and will simplify your getting the ID with JQuery.

If it's possible, have the PHP gen unique IDs for the DIVS while still classing them as 'ticket_details' as **tjameson** suggests.

PS (to moderators) this question has little to do with the ColorBox pulgin and everything to do with Jquery selection.